# I rm python3.9 can i get it back ,

Tags: python, linux, file, filesystems, apt

I am new on linux and i tried to change the Symbolic link of python3 in /usr/bin/ ,
and i accidentally remove the python3.9 file !
But i know i didn't delete it completely Because  there is still a lot of file called python3.9 .
After that 'apt' didn't work anymore and i got this error :

```
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
```

Now , I only have version 2.7 of python and i can't install another because apt don't work !!

This is the result of
[image: ls /usr/bin/python*] :

So I hope someone can help me and I wish you a good afternoon

Comment: `python3` https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3&searchon=names ... ... Turn off the computer → Run a live OS / the install media → Download python3 and copy the missing file(s) to the OS.

Comment: if you use Ubuntu or similar then you may try to download precompiled Python for Ubuntu from unofficial repo [deadsnakes](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages) and unpack missing file from `.deb` But they may have newer version which may not work with your version. OR when you download `.deb` you may use `dpkg` to install it - and then it doesn't have to use `apt`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: As you've lost `apt` command meaning you can't install or remove anything using `apt` command.

The possible way to fix this is by reinstalling respective *apt-package* of your *architecture* and then do the below python installation.

To install apt-package again download the `.deb` file from the `“/etc/apt/sources.list”` file. Lots of links for installation and upgrades for packages will be in this file.

Now find the downloading source using `$cat /etc/apt/sources.list` command.

Find `/pool/main/a/apt/` directory under downloading source and then download the `.deb` file which matches your *architecture* and download it.

Thereafter install this using `dpkg` command like this

```
sudo dpkg -i PackageName.deb
```

Replace the *PackageName* with your file name (e.g- apt_1.6.13_arm64/apt_1.9.3_i386).

Restart the PC and then check the `/usr/bin/` directory to ensure if it had properly installed .
If you get nothing there then run *locate apt-get* command to locate it. If you can't get it then there is no other way than reinstalling the OS itself.

If you have reinstalled apt then
use the following commands to freshly install Python.

Note that all the commands below  will be for Python3 as you're concerned with version 3.9.

```
    # To uninstall the Python only
sudo apt-get remove python3.9

   # To uninstall the Python with all the packages also
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python3.9

   # To remove all the dependencies and configuration files 
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python3.9
```

Now to install the Python3. The following command will install the latest version of python3. which to this date is python3.9.

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

You can use pip to manage the python packages also.
To install pip use the following command

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Now to manage the python packages using pip

```
# To install package; replace PackageName with the name of package(like flask)
sudo pip install PackageName

# To uninstall package
sudo pip uninstall PackageName
```

If you get trouble with pip get list of all the commands pip uses with

```
sudo pip help
```

You can list all the Python version installed (on default location)
`ls /usr/bin/python*`

Hope this will help in resolving the problem.